# Read, encrypt, zip and send a file without rewriting it

Tags: java, scala, io, inputstream, outputstream

I have a to read a file, zip it, encrypt it with AES algorithm and send it to an S3 bucket.

The workflow of my actual code is :

1. Read file and write it as a zip file (`Files.copy(filePath, zipOutputStream)` from `java.nio.file`
2. Read the zip file, encrypt and rewrite it

"Pseudocode" for 1. and 2.

```
    fileList.foreach(localFile => {
      zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(localFile.toPath.getFileName.toString))
      file.Files.copy(localFile.toPath, zipOutputStream)
      encryptAndReplace(localFile, someEncryptionConfig)
    })
```

3. Read the encrypted zip and send it to s3 (`FileInputStream` to `S3OutputStreamWrapper`)

I want to do all those steps without rewriting the file 2 times and avoid IO to save time.

How can i process to optimize my workflow ?

If i return an InputStream in my step 1. instead of rewriting it. And then re-return an InputStream in my step 2. and then send it to S3,  does is means that my 2 methods will return the whole file ?
And that my whole file will be stored in memory ?
What should i take care of if I process in this way ?

Comment: If it's all in- and outputstreams, it just 'streams' (hence the name). Even if you process GBs worth of data, the memory footprint of your app will be quite small (the 'streaming' will take a few MB primarily for the zip block structure, but it's a constant value - process twice the data, zero change to the memory load), and you won't need any disk space either.

Comment: So there is no problem if instead of writing a file after encrypting it, I return an `InputStream` that my zipping function will take as a parameter ?

Comment: Yup, that's fine. That's kinda what they are designed for :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read and write the file for encryption. Using `CipherOutputStream` you can do everything in one go.

```
Cipher cipher = ...;
try (OutputStream fileOut = Files.newOutputStream(...);
        CipherOutputStream cipherOut = new CipherOutputStream(fileOut, cipher);
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(cipherOut)) {

    // add entries to zipOut
}
```

I think you can even replace `fileOut` with the `S3OutputStreamWrapper` and do everything in one go.